# Почему не записывается значение в свойство элемента Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Нужно записать данные в свойство инфоблока "DETAIL_PICTURE".
Пробую так:

```
$value = 123;
CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValues ( 40188, 12, array("VALUE" => $value), "DETAIL_PICTURE" );
```

Вывожу:

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "XML_ID", "DETAIL_PICTURE");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => 12, "ACTIVE_DATE" => "Y", "ACTIVE" => "Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array(), $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arFields);
    echo "</pre>";
}

Array
(
    [ID] => 40188
    [~ID] => 40188
    [NAME] => Дн026
    [~NAME] => Дн026
    [XML_ID] => Т_26
    [~XML_ID] => Т_26
    [DETAIL_PICTURE] => 
    [~DETAIL_PICTURE] => 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что "DETAIL_PICTURE", не свойство, а поле, вам необходимо использовать 
[update element](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/update.php) 
Если у вас  переменной $value храниться id файла, то можно воспользоваться

```
CFile::GetByID($value);
```

Если необходимо обновить 1 элемент

```
$el = new CIBlockElement;

$arLoadProductArray = Array(
  "MODIFIED_BY"    => $USER->GetID(), // элемент изменен текущим пользователем
  "DETAIL_PICTURE" => CFile::GetByID($value)
  );

$PRODUCT_ID = 2;  // Id элемента который необходимо изменить (обновить)
$res = $el->Update($PRODUCT_ID, $arLoadProductArray);
```

Если необходимо обновить несколько, то сначала необходимо найти элементы, а затем через цикл обновить